# Python: How to run multiple files at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, os.system

I'm trying to create a For-loop which automatically starts different python files at the exact same time, but they always seem to run one after one.

```
import os
import multiprocessing
import p1, p2, p3

#first idea

path = "C:" + "\\Users\\Max\\\\Desktop\\\python\\tasks\\"
tasks = ['p1.py', 'p2.py', 'p3.py']
len = tasks.__len__()
ind = 0
for i in range(len):
    os.system('python' + ' ' + tasks[ind])
    ind += 1

#second idea

for x in ('p1', 'p2', 'p3'):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=lambda: __import__(x))
    p.start()
```

p1, p2, p3 are the files I'm trying to run at the same time, but they get executed one after one, so if the code is:

```
time.sleep(10)
print("hello)
```

I will have to wait 30 seconds for the program to be done, instead of the 10 seconds I want.

Comment: If, as seems, you don't care about the output, it is probably even easier (albeit quick and dirty) to do this as a shell script: `for f in *.py; do python $f &; done`. (Except you're running windows and I don't know how the command-line works there.)

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do though? Surely your plan is not just to write three "hello"s in the end?

Comment: @AKX I'm trying to open different links at the same time in my browser with the webbrowser module. Essentially                                                                           time.sleep(10)       webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com")                                              But the link is different in each file

Answer (score 4):

If you want to start the files in three separate interpreters, start them as subprocesses:

```py
import subprocess
path = r"C:\Users\Max\Desktop\python\tasks"
tasks = ['1.py', '2.py', '3.py']
task_processes = [
    subprocess.Popen(r'python %s\%s' % (path, task), shell=True)
    for task
    in tasks
]
for task in task_processes:
    task.wait()
```

Comment: this somewhat worked, however it seems to execute it once where it still runs one atfer one file, it then repeats the process and executes them at the same time like I want it to.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep using multiprocessing, you can just encapsulate your system calls in a function:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

path = "C:\\Users\\Max\\\\Desktop\\\python\\tasks\\"
tasks = ['1.py', '2.py', '3.py']

def foo(task):
    os.system('python ' + path + task)

for task in tasks:
    p = Process(target=foo, args=(task,))
    p.start()
```

Comment: This doesn't do what I want, at first this runs all files one after one, then the next loop it runs each file three times. I just want all three files to be run once at the same time.

Comment: My code works fine, it's been tested. Please make sure you're not executing something else or share your edited code/output for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP's actual goal from a comment:

> I'm trying to open different links at the same time in my browser with the webbrowser module. Essentially `time.sleep(10) webbrowser.open("google.com")` But the link is different in each file

we can instead use threads. I added the option for a different delay per URL, because otherwise there'd be no point in having each thread sleep on its own.

```py
import webbrowser
import threading
import time


def delayed_open_url(delay, url):
    time.sleep(delay)
    webbrowser.open(url)


threads = []
for delay, url in [
    (3, "http://google.com"),
    (5, "http://example.com"),
    (11, "http://stackoverflow.com"),
]:
    threads.append(
        threading.Thread(target=delayed_open_url, args=(url,)).start()
    )

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()  # Wait for each thread

# This code will be executed after each thread is done
```